# Прототип игры-консольного приложения на языке Java

Tags: java, ооп, разработка-игр, консоль, проектирование

Подскажите люди умные!

С чего начать? Только учу ООП

---

Создать прототип игры-консольного приложения на языке Java.

В игре создается отряд определенной расы, состоящий из одного мага, трех лучников и четырех бойцов.
Предусмотрено четыре расы: эльфы, люди, орки, нежить. Эльфы и люди играют против орков и нежити.

С начала игры каждый персонаж имеет уровень жизни равный 100 HP.
Выводить ход игры в консоль: вести статистику ходов с порядком ходов (кто, кого, нанесенный урон, умер).

Порядок ходов для рас определяется случайным образом.

Возможности персонажей:

- Раса эльфов:

  - маг:

    - наложение улучшения на персонажа своего отряда
    - нанесение урона персонажу противника магией на 10 HP
  - лучник:

    - стрелять из лука (нанесение урона 7 HP)
    - атаковать противника (нанесение урона 3 HP)
  - воин:

    - атаковать мечом (нанесение урона 15 HP)
- Раса людей:

  - маг:

    - наложение улучшения на персонажа своего отряда.
    - атаковать магией (нанесение урона 4 HP)
  - арбалетчик:

    - стрелять из арбалета (нанесение урона 5 HP)
    - атаковать (нанесение урона 3 HP)
  - воин:

    - атаковать мечом (нанесение урона 18 HP)
- Раса орков:

  - шаман:

    - наложение улучшения на персонажа своего отряда.
    - наложение проклятия (снятие улучшения с персонажа противника для следующего хода)
  - лучник:

    - стрелять из лука (нанесение урона 3 HP)
    - удар клинком (нанесение урона 2 HP)
  - гоблин:

    - атака дубиной (нанесение урона 20 HP)
- Раса нежити:

  - некромант:

    - наслать недуг (уменьшение силы урона персонажа противника на 50% на один ход)
    - атака (нанесение урона 5 HP)
  - охотник:

    - стрелять из лука (нанесение урона 4 HP)
    - атаковать (нанесение урона 2 HP)
  - зомби:

    - удар копьем (нанесение урона 18 HP)

Comment: вам следует больше узнать про параметры, ооп и обобщение чтобы код не дублировать огромные части кода https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Придется создавать для каждого из классов каждой расы отдельный класс(от расы только название, ни одной фактической особенности, типа уникального поля(которое на все производное от расы распространяется)). Но их можно наследовать от единого класса(Персонаж), куда можно поместить универсальные переменные, константы, методы. А затем можно создать классы Стрелок и Пехотинец. Не думаю, что создать универсальный класс Мага получится, ведь у них разные способности.

Думаю, все взаимодействия нужно производить через отдельный класс. Вот там и записывайте ход боя.